# SQL Report Builder: How to merge groups?

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I have two reports, one I created and another I'm using as kind of a guide/template. In the template report, the column grouping appears to be "merged", but that's probably not the right term for this scenario (hence my trouble in Googling this further). Here is what my template looks like:

**TEMPLATE**

[image]
[image]

---

However, mine looks a little different. I have both my year and month grouping, but if I merge them (by selecting both cells and click Merge inside the Layout section), I lose the "month" group. Here's how mine looks:

**MINE**

[image]
[image]

So how do I mimic the style of the template? I see that the two groups in my template both have parentheses around them, whereas in mine, the parentheses only exist for my child group. Is that my problem? What does this signify?

---

For further clarity, here's essentially what I'm trying to get the output to look like (column for 8/2019, column for 9/2019, etc.) 
[image]

VERSUS

What I have (column for year, sub-column for month) 
[image]

Comment: In case anyone reading this was wondering about the parentheses difference between my two examples, I believe I uncovered that. The parentheses appears to refer to whether or not the column exists (when you add a group, it automatically tries to add a column header) and that is when you have your column name WITHOUT parentheses. Delete the column only (not the group, additionally) and parentheses will appear around your group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was prepared to tell you that you must've gotten a warning message before your group disappeared.  But to my surprise, the group disappears just like you said it would.

Instead of merging the fields, follow these steps:

- Select the row that contains the year textbox.
- Right-click, and select "delete rows"
- When prompted, mark "Delete rows only".
- Enter the textbox that has '[month]'
- Place your cursor after '[month]'.
- Type in a "/".
- Without leaving focus from inside the box, right-click and select "Create Placeholder".
- In the properties box, set the value to `Fields!year.Value`.

As for the parentheses around the group names.  Seems that it may have to do with the fact that the group isn't represented in a particular way in the structure.  You can read [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e3afa095-5cc3-4d25-a2c5-0f397cf584b9/where-did-the-row-group-parentheses-come-from?forum=sqlreportingservices) to learn a little more.  But the report always works as I expect with or without them so I don't pay them much attention.

Comment: Thank you SO much! Grouping in report builder has been where I've been struggling the most. I must have had a slightly different setup than you anticipated, but I still managed to essentially use your directions to get what I needed, including concatenating the month and year. It now looks and works beautifully.